# Redisson doesn't set TTL or cache name correctly

Tags: spring, maven, caching, redis, redisson

I'm creating a Spring application that uses Redis cache via redisson client.

```
 @Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(RedissonClient redissonClient) throws IOException {

    Map<String, CacheConfig> config = new HashMap<String,CacheConfig>();
    config.put("employeesCache", new CacheConfig(24*60*1000, 12*60*1000));
    RedissonSpringCacheManager manager= new RedissonSpringCacheManager(redissonClient, config);

    return manager;
}
```

However when running this application the cache name created in Redis is `{employeesCache}:redisson_options` instead of just `employeesCache`.

Also, when I check for the TTL in the Redis CLI it returns `(integer) -1` ,meaning it has not been set.

So the RedissonSpringCacheManager is partially functioning, it creates the cache but without any configuration, can you help me fix it.

I'm using the following Maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redisson` **use a map to save your data**, but keys in the map are not support TTL, so `Redisson` maintain a `{employeesCache}:redisson_options` to save the  configurations, your employeesCache keys is maintained and deleted by `redisson`, **NOT** `redis`

So, your data will be saved in a map called `employeesCache`, not in `{employeesCache}:redisson_options`, just leave it alone.

Comment: thanks,but do you know how to use this map, because in the `@Cacheable` annotation from `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;` , I need to set the cache name, when I try to do `@Cacheable(value ="{employeesCache}:redisson_options", key = "#id")` it works however if I tried `@Cacheable(value ="employeesCache}", key = "#id")`  the caching doesn't work!

Comment: Or is there a manual way to use the map (to search,delete and save a key) instead of using the annotation? Can you recommend me a resource to find more information.

Comment: @User01 The cache name is `employeesCache`, NOT `employeesCache}`, check your spelling. `@Cacheable(value ="employeesCache",  key = "#id")` is correct.

Comment: Sorry I spelled it correctly in the code but it doesn't work.

Comment: @User01 
You need to provide more code (example project is better), or I can't help you. You can start with a simple project (integrate with redisson only) to see if it works, other modules may cause the bug.
**NOTE**: Redisson 3.13.1 is using `redisson-spring-data-22`, which is compatible with Spring boot **2.2.X**, if you are using 2.3+, you need choose another version, see [HERE](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/tree/master/redisson-spring-boot-starter#1-add-redisson-spring-boot-starter-dependency-into-your-project)

Comment: Here is the example project [link](https://github.com/AseelAbushhadeh/Redis-cache.git) you can find the redisson configuration at :src/main/java/com/example/demo/redissonConfig.java , and the class that's using the `@cachable` is at src/main/java/com/example/demo/Employees/EmployeeService.java

Comment: I tried to use the dependency redisson-spring-data-22 but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it seems that the `value` and `cacheManager` attributes need to have the same value, i.e. `employeesCache`

```
@Cacheable(
        key = CacheUtil.CachePrefixes.SOME_PREFIX + "#userId.toString()",
        value = ["employeesCache"],
        cacheManager = "employeesCache"
    )
```

Please note that `value` accept `Array<String>` in my case, here is the gist code from Cacheable.java

```
@AliasFor("cacheNames")
String[] value() default {};
```

Only in this way, I got to manage to set `ttl` and `maxIdleTime`, together with creating multiple cacheManagers